Is there a way to extract shaders from an APK?
I have an APK of a game and I want to extract the graphics shaders (OpenGL or Spir-V shader) from it. Where are the shaders exactly located and How OpenGL shaders are stored in an apk?
As far as I see it should be somewhere in the assets folder:

Any help is appreciated!

Also be aware of: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity
